# How to pass multiple values from view to controller trough an action in Ember.js?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

I have the following text input

```
<input type="text" name="item-name" value={{item.name}} onblur={{action "confirmName" value="target.value"}} />
```

How can I pass not only `target.value` but also the related item to `confirmName`?

What should I edit?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Ember will automatically fill `item.name` with whatever you type inside the input. Why do you want to pass in the input value and the item into an action?

Comment: Yes. I would like to validate the new name only on blur

Comment: sorry, i just realized I clicked it by accident instead of an upvote :), if you edit your question I'll re-vote

Comment: Ok thanks :p Please boost my reputation!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found how to do it:

```
onblur={{action "confirmName" item1 item2}}
```

Unfortunately it seams impossible to pass the value.target.

The action arguments are given this way:

```
actions: {
    confirmName: function(item1, item2, event) {
    }
}
```

Comment: is there any way around this? I have a dynamically generated form, and need to pass a model and a quantity to the action

Comment: To retrieve `value.target`, in the action function make sure you have the `event` argument, and then get it using `event.value.target`